# Self made python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I defined two class in a separated file (which name is `MyClass.py`) from my main program and I am trying to include it. The class definition is as follows:

```
class MyClass: 
    Tn=""

    def _init_(self,TN):
            self.Tn=TN
```

while my main program is as follows

```
import MyClass as MC

obj=MC.MyClass("hello")
print(obj.Tn)
```

And when I try to launch it the following message appear: `"name 'Team_class 'is not defined"`. This makes me think that it doesn't import the class correctly but I don't seem to understand the reason.

Comment: Can you please share information about where `Team_class` is defined ?

Comment: It's very unlikely that the code in question produces an error message referring to "Team_class". Object creation will fail because `_init_` is not `__init__`. Please post actual code, not an approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, your class' `__init__()` method is wrong. I don't know if you just copied it here wrong, but try this:

```
class MyClass: 
    # __init__() is a magic method and needs two underscores, not one

    def __init__(self, tn=''):
            # Giving a default value in your __init__() method
            # is the more straightforward way of doing this

            # It is also more pythonic to name your variables in snake_case

            self.tn = tn
```

Then in your main file:

```
import MyClass as mc

obj = mc.MyClass('Hello')
print(obj.tn)  # Hello
```

**But can you show us where `Team_class` is used in order to resolve your error?**

Comment: Problem was `_init_` instead of `__init__`. Sorry for the dumb question, I'm new to python